# (Fast) Algorithms for decomposing polyominoes into rectangles

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, big-list, computational-geometry

Here are some [polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino):
[image]

The general definition of a polyomino allows for holes (I think). This question restricts itself to those polyominoes that are hole-free.

It would be nice if the algorithms were characterized by their $O(f(n))$ cost in time, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the polyomino.

Comment: Did you mean *decomposing rectangles into polyominoes*? For eg. your figure shows examples of polyominos containing $5$ unit squares and *decomposing* all these polyominoes in this case would only yield the first one as $5$ is prime.

Comment: What about just splitting an $n$-omino to $n$ little squares?

Comment: I imagine the objective is to decompose a polyomino in a minimum number of rectangles (so 1, 2 or 3 rectangles in all these examples).

Comment: @vvg no, I mean decomposing polyominoes into rectangles

Comment: @VTand see Lourrran's comment

Although oftentimes, we might want to loosen the restriction of trying to minimize the number of rectangles produced if it's faster (for example) to decompose a polyomino into 3 rectangles instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia page [Polygon partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_partition#Minimizing_the_number_of_components) gives references for some relevant surveys, including one by
[Keil, J. M. (2000). Polygon Decomposition. Handbook of computational geometry, 2, 491-518](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-044482537-7/50012-7). In particular, Section 3.1 "Partitioning orthogonal polygons" has references for multiple algorithms to partition a [rectilinear/orthogonal polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon) into minimum number of rectangles, both approximate and exact algorithms. Polyominoes can be considered as rectilinear polygons, so the algorithms should also work for polyominoes.

One of the referenced papers from the survey is "Minimum partitioning simple rectilinear polygons in O(n log log n) - time" by W. T. Liou, J. J. Tan, and R. C. Lee, published in 1989. The publication can be found in https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/73833.73871.